# Pdf Reader in Android using Rmsdk

Tags: java, android-ndk

Please help me in using rmsdk library to read the pdf in Android. Can i get the source code of pdf Reader using Rmsdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) This is something that is not just available for anyone to download, some companies go through a lot to not just simply disclose their source code for such applications.

Hope this helps, although I do not think that you will succeed on your quest for an open source implementation of this, please do share it here if you do.

Answer (score -1):

You can downbload the DLreader a complete sample viewer apk provided with RMSDK here: http://www.datalogics.com/products/ebook/rmsdk/dlreader
So this is the free code that uses rmsdk library that you need. You can use as is as a complete pdf reader, and of course you can modify it and customize it by yourself.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.